# Nodejs keep showing "WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled."

Tags: node.js, npm

I tried the solution that was suggested but no use, I also reinstall my node but it still showing "WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled."

[image: p1]

[image: p2]

Comment: Try deleting the "node_modules folder" and "package-lock.json file" and then run "npm install" this should install everything fresh Dep and devDep.

Comment: I did try that, unfortunately that didnt work ,but i finally fixed it by using” npm config set force false”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed it by using `npm config set force false`.